# How to get the objects from superclass to subclass in java?

Tags: java

A class `Person` has several subclasses including `Employee`.

There is a method which is supposed to return another `List` which consists of just the `Employee` objects from the original list of `Person`.

How do I accomplish this in Java?

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow. Unfortunately your question is at very low quality. Do some research and show us what did you tried up to now. And please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking.

Comment: Please post your  `Person` and `Employee` class to get a better idea about your question.

Comment: `List<Person> employees = people.stream().filter((Person t) -> t instanceof Employee).collect(Collectors.toList());` - as a single line idea

Answer (score 2):

Simple example for you:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> lst = new ArrayList<Person>() {
        {
            add(new Person());
            add(new Person());
            add(new Employee());
            add(new Employee());
            add(new AnotherPerson());
            add(new AnotherPerson());
        }
    };

    List<Person> employes = lst.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof Employee).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(employes.size());
}

class Person {

}

class Employee extends Person {

}

class AnotherPerson extends Person {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since

> Person has several subclasses

and

> return another List which consists of just the Employee objects

You shall use `instanceOf` to accomplish looking for specifically looking for `Employee` class from a `List<Person>`. Just for e.g:

```
List<Person> personList // assigned to something
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Person person : personList)  {
    if(person !=null && person instanceOf Employee) { 
        employeeList.add((Employee) person);
    }
}
```

The sample from [java-nutsandbolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) might help you.

> When using the instanceof operator, keep in mind that `null` is not an
>   instance of anything.

Comment: are there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: @IT-KOKO instanceOf is far the safest way when you have multiple sub classes of Person.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers and comments should provide a solution, but if you want a generic solution, then you could do something like this:

```
public static <T extends Person> List<T> getPersonTypes(Class<T> cls, Collection<Person> c)
{
  return c.stream()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .filter(p -> cls.isAssignableFrom(p.getClass()))
      .map(cls::cast)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then call something like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = getPersonTypes(Employee.class, listOfPersons);
```